# How programs can be compiled on multiple platform using delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I was developing Java and android applications but I have changed my decision using Delphi to develop my apps.But ı dont understand how can we compile our programs on different platforms(ios,windows,android) ? Delphi use any virtual machine for this like java or what ?

Comment: This is not a question for StackOverflow.  If you are thinking about purchasing Delphi and you have questions about its functionality then this is a question you should be asking an Embarcadero sales representative.  If you would like to try using Delphi before buying, you can download a free trial and see for yourself how it works : http://www.embarcadero.com/downloads

Comment: Why is this such a bad question. The asker just doesn't quite understand how Delphi can create applications that don't rely on a VM.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It feels like a really weak question to me.  The wiki for "cross-compiler" is the first entry on a google search for `how can we compile our programs on different platforms`  http://goo.gl/OYz5zO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Delphi mobile compilers are what is known as [cross-compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler). Although the compilers execute on Windows, they produce executables for a different platform. In the case of Android, the compiler produces native ARM executables. All the Delphi compilers produces native executables, in the sense that the code emitted by the compiler runs natively on the target hardware, and not under a virtual machine.

In fact, all the numerous Delphi compilers other than the 32 bit Windows compiler dcc32 are cross compilers. Even the 64 bit Windows compiler, dcc64 is a 32 bit x86 executable which produces 64 bit x64 output, and so is a cross-compiler.

The other factor that makes cross-platform Delphi viable is the FireMonkey framework (FMX) that presents a single uniform interface independent of the target platform. The implementation of FMX is different on different platforms, but from the application programmer's perspective, a single common interface is offered. This means that the application programmer can write code once, and then compile for each target platform.

Comment: The really sweet part here is that there is not just a cross-compiler but also a remote debugger (and the client side helper called the platform assistant) to let you debug your Android, iOS or Mac OS X apps.